# Save CDTStore (NSObject subclass) to NSUserDefaults in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile, ios8

The CDTStore class is a class cluster that abstracts a common interface for local and remote Cloudant data stores.  Local data stores use the CDTDatastore and remote data stores use REST API to modify the remote data store.

I need to save an CDTStore object in the user defaults, to later retrieve it. (initially the reason is: CDTStore object gets destroyed after the app goes to background after some time, therefore not allowing to save objects to db anymore).

The header of the class looks like this:

```
...
@interface CDTStore : NSObject
...
```

I have read this link: 
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/16205-saving-class-nsuserdefaults.html
His code (smithdale87):

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
       //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.question forKey:@"question"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.categoryName forKey:@"category"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.subCategoryName forKey:@"subcategory"];
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
           //decode properties, other class vars
        self.question = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"question"];
        self.categoryName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"category"];
        self.subCategoryName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"subcategory"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

but the problem is that in case of CDTStore things are much more complex. Is there an easier way to do it? Or, if not, how to do it using his method?

Comment: you header class source is not visible

Comment: does CDTStore has some custom classes as well or all are foundation classes?